# Bash - for range no longer works as wanted when one of the ends is a variable

Tags: bash, variable-substitution, brace-expansion

```
#!/bin/bash
myfirstarray=(1 3 5 7 9 11)
for i in {2..4}
    do
    for j in {1..${myfirstarray[$((i-1))]}}
        do
            echo ${j}
        done
    done
```

In the code above the range of the outer loop is interpreted as wanted, iterating from `2` to `4`. Both substitutions in the range of the inner loop also work. However the inner range is interpreted as a string and not a range of integers. How can I fix this issue?

Expected:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Result:

```
{1..3}
{1..5}
{1..7}
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash, brace expansion is done before other expansion, and you can't use expansion inside them. That's one of the most frequently asked questions here.

Though you could use another shell like `zsh` (where `{x..y}` comes from) or `ksh93` or `yash -o braceexpand` to work around the problem, in general you don't want to use brace expansion in `for` loops as doing `for i in {1..1000000}` for instance involves storing the full list of numbers in memory several times for no good reason. It's almost as bad as using `for i in $(seq 1000000)`.

You'd rather use the C-like loops from ksh93:

```
#! /bin/bash -
myfirstarray=(1 3 5 7 9 11)
for (( i = 2; i <= 4; i++ )); do
  for (( j = 1; j <= myfirstarray[i-1]; j++ )); do
     echo "$j"
  done
done
```

I also removed the split+glob invocation in your code which made no sense.

Switching to zsh would have other advantages. For instance, the code above could look like:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
myfirstarray=(1 3 5 7 9 11)
for i ({2..4}) for j ({1..$myfirstarray[i]}) echo $j
```

Or:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
myfirstarray=(1 3 5 7 9 11)
for i ($myfirstarray[2,4]) for j ({1..$i}) echo $j
```

Comment: What means the `-` after `bash` after  the _shebang_ ?

Comment: @GillesQuenot see [Why the "-" in the "#! /bin/sh -" shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/351729)