# How to run a script without sh prefix inside the container

Tags: shell-script, docker, container

We are running containers on open shift platform.  The application pods are running fine.  We able to login to the pod using the below command

```
oc exec -it <podname> -- /bin/bash
```

also `tried /bin/sh`

once login we are trying to execute a script which is available in a particular folder (/opt/scripts)

When we run `sh script` it works. When we run `script` without `sh` it throws `command not found`

Inside the script we have `#!bin/ksh` (tried with bash and also sh)

How can I run the `script` without `sh` prefix

**Update:**
Tried to simulate the scenario inside the container

Below are the installed shells inside the container

```
sh-4.4$ cat /etc/shells 
/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/usr/bin/sh
/usr/bin/bash
```

This is a script.  The first line is updated

```
sh-4.4$ more tRun
#!/bin/sh
```

Runs only with prefix `sh` or `bash`

```
sh-4.4$ tRun
sh: tRun: command not found

sh-4.4$ sh tRun
JAVA_HOME is not set. Unexpected results may occur.
Set JAVA_HOME to the directory of your local JDK to avoid this message.
Please enter aguments:
^C

sh-4.4$ bash tRun
JAVA_HOME is not set. Unexpected results may occur.
Set JAVA_HOME to the directory of your local JDK to avoid this message.
Please enter aguments:
^C
```

Comment: That `#!bin/ksh` should likely be `#! /bin/ksh -` (the missing `/` is the most important missing part) or `#! /bin/bash -` or `#! /bin/sh -` if `/bin/ksh` doesn't exist in that container but `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh` does and the script doesn't use Korn-specific extensions not also found in bash/sh

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead

Comment: screenshot replaced with text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run “on its own”, your script needs the command given in its shebang to be available. Since that’s `/bin/ksh`, it needs `ksh` to be installed in your container image.

If your script actually works correctly with `sh`, you can instead change its shebang to `#!/bin/sh` (or better still, [`#!/bin/sh -`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/351729/86440)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I tried the same but unable to fix.  Updated my question for better understanding.

Comment: it works now... there was one more missing is the $PATH.